# Favicon doesn't show up only in Chrome but in Explorer, Mozilla, Opera and Edge shows up

Tags: html, browser, favicon

Hello I have a problem with my favicon - it doesn't show up in Chrome. I've tested it in Explorer, Mozilla, Opera and Edge and everything is ok but in Chrome it doesn't show up.

my code:

```
 <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/img/cattery/logo-little.png"/>
```

I've tried clearing browsing data, changing link, changing .png into .ico etc.

I think that there is sth wrong with browser beacuse another browsers don't have problems to show up my favicon.

Comment: Have you tried a hard refresh? Ctrl+Shift+R for browsers on Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting it sizes parameters. It should work.

```html
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/icons/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/icons/favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/icons/favicon.ico">
```

Answer (score 1):

If your favicon works everywhere but Chrome, this is probably because the `head` section of your page contains a non-`head` markup (ie. a `body`-only markup). For example, there might be a `div` in your `head`.

When this happens, Chrome has a unique behavior: it considers your `head` to be closed and `body` implicitly starts (because a `div` fits only in `body` after all). And the `head`-only markups which follow (such as your favicon markups) the misplaced `div` are ignored, since they have nothing to do in the `body`.